# C++/Cx is it possible to call CreateTask().then with a String instead of a IAsyncAction?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, task, c++-cx

Basically I have the next function that I need to call Async:

```
void waitForFrames(){

CMFTWrapper::IsRunning = true;
while (CMFTWrapper::IsRunning){
    result = WaitForSingleObjectEx(CMFTWrapper::FrameEvent, INFINITE, true);
    if (result != WAIT_OBJECT_0){
        // capture aborted, quit. 
    }
    else if (CMFTWrapper::count > 0){
        // copy the bitmap data
    }
}
}
```

Now I tried doing it like this:

```
create_task(waitForFrames())
    .then([this](task<void> frameTask)
        {
            XTRACE(L"=================================FINISHED WITH FRAME TASK\n");
        });
```

This gives me the next error:

```
Error   26  error C2228: left of '.then' must have class/struct/union   C:\Users\Alin Rosu\Workspace\vidyomobile_windows_phone\Vidyo.DeviceManager\WinRT\DeviceDetection\LmiVideoCapturerWinRTImplementation.cpp    181 1   Vidyo.DeviceManager
Error   24  error C2784: 'Concurrency::task<_Ty> Concurrency::create_task(const Concurrency::task<_Ty> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const Concurrency::task<_Ty> &' from 'void'    C:\Users\Alin Rosu\Workspace\vidyomobile_windows_phone\Vidyo.DeviceManager\WinRT\DeviceDetection\LmiVideoCapturerWinRTImplementation.cpp    180 1   Vidyo.DeviceManager
Error   25  error C2784: 'Concurrency::task<details::_TaskTypeFromParam<_Ty>::_Type> Concurrency::create_task(_Ty,Concurrency::task_options)' : could not deduce template argument for '_Ty' from 'void'    C:\Users\Alin Rosu\Workspace\vidyomobile_windows_phone\Vidyo.DeviceManager\WinRT\DeviceDetection\LmiVideoCapturerWinRTImplementation.cpp    180 1   Vidyo.DeviceManager
Error   45  error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\Alin Rosu\Workspace\vidyomobile_windows_phone\Build\ARM\Release\Vidyo.DeviceManager\LmiDeviceManagerWinRT.lib'    C:\Users\Alin Rosu\Workspace\vidyomobile_windows_phone\Vidyo.DeviceManager.Test\LINK    Vidyo.DeviceManager.Test
```

Now I tried changing the return value of the function to other stuff from void (Dword, int) but still I get a similar error.
Watching over examples I found on the net, all the functions that use this, that I found return back IAsyncAction.
Example:

```
create_task(m_pMediaCapture->StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(m_EncodingProfile, m_recordStorageFile))
                    .then([this](task<void> recordTask)
                {
                    XTRACE(L"=================================will try to get record task\n");
}
```

How can I do this with my normal function, so that it can run async?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a lambda directly to the create_task function:

`create_task( [](){ /* code here */ } )`.

So in your scenario the following should work:

```
create_task([](){ waitForFrames(); })
.then([this](task<void> frameTask){
            XTRACE(L"=================================FINISHED WITH FRAME TASK\n");
});
```